# What does catch { throw; } do?

Tags: c#

I just found this gem in the pile of spaghetti I have to maintain:

```
try { Foo(); }
catch { throw; }
```

Is it safe to replace it with

```
Foo();
```

?

Comment: Yes, those two statements are equal in what they do. However 1st one does one extra throw if exception occurs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes**. It's exactly the same. Maybe someone used it to put a breakpoint in the catch block.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is safe to delete try/catch here. Often such code created in iterations: initially it was exceptions processing there, but later it was lazily removed.